# Bind ItemsPanelTemplate to property of ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

I am trying to create a custom MessageBox with variable number of buttons, this number being equal to the Count of ItemsSource. The buttons are to be placed in a UniformGrid. ItemsSource of ButtonView is assigned to ObservableCollection Buttons. Buttons.Count is not recognized by the code. How could I correctly assign UniformGrid Columns value?

```
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="2" x:Name="ButtonView">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding Buttons.Count}">
                </UniformGrid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="Button">
                <Button Margin="2" Content="{Binding Content}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Be aware that when you assign a collection of UIElement or a derived type to the ItemsSource of an ItemsControl, the ItemTemplate is ignored, because the items don't need to be "templated". A DataTemplate for a Button that creates a new Button with `Content="{Binding Content}"` does obviously not make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Rows` property instead of `Columns`:

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```